# Number of unramified quadratic extensions of a number field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Is there a general formula for the number of unramified quadratic extensions of a number field $K$?

When $K$ is quadratic, this is known (by genus theory) to be $2^{\omega(\Delta_K)-1}$, where $\omega(n)$ denotes the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ and $\Delta_K$ is the discriminant of $K$. I'm interested in results for when $K$ is of higher degree.

It seems like this problem might be much harder and is maybe adjacent to understanding the two-torsion of the class group $\text{Cl}_K$ (which seems [hard](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02458.pdf) when $K$ is not quadratic), but I'm pretty new to the area and could be totally off-base. Is there any hope of a more direct approach?

Comment: "is maybe adjacent": it is in fact completely equivalent.

Comment: The unramified abelian extensions of $K$ are in bijection with the subgroups of $\text{Cl}_K$.

Comment: @abx In particular, it is "maybe adjacent".

Comment: @GHfromMO I agree, by HIlbert Class Field I guess.

Comment: @abx Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but it's not clear to me what the two-torsion of the class field group tells us about the index-two subgroups. If I'm not mistaken, the latter is what I want but the former is what seems very hard?

Comment: @bean However, #A[2] equals #Hom(A,Z/2Z) by duality.

Comment: Oh I see - thanks that makes sense! Would one of you want to write this up as an answer or shall I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer seems to be no.

1. The number of unramified quadratic extensions of $K$ is equal to the number of index-two subgroups of the ideal class group $\text{Cl}_K$ by class field theory.
2. The index-two subgroups of $\text{Cl}_K$ correspond to the non-zero elements of $\text{Hom}(\text{Cl}_K, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.
3. $\#\text{Hom}(\text{Cl}_K, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) = \#\text{Cl}_K[2]$ by Pontryagin duality, as pointed out to me by @RP_ and @abx in the comments.
4. The problem of computing (or even bounding) the size of $\#\text{Cl}_K[2]$ when $K$ is not a quadratic extension appears to be under [active study](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02458.pdf) and seems to be a challenging problem in general.